# laravel combined query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  `dateofjoining` >=  '2016-03-05'
AND  `dateofjoining` <=  '2016-03-09'
AND (
`login_username` LIKE  '%bala%'
OR  `phoneno` LIKE  '%987%'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Laravel query:

But in my laravel query login_username is some time set null and my phonenumber also some time set null. In that below query i am getting error for laravel "$username" variable is undefied.

```
$lists = Users::where ( function ( $query ) {
              $query->where('login_username','like','%'.$username.'%')
                    ->or_where("phoneno", "LIKE", '%'.$username.'%');
         })->whereBetween('dateofjoining',array($fromDate, $toDate))  
         ->paginate(5);
```

Is there any mistake in my query?

Comment: i have added the answer below, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your where condition,
Just replace your code with this one:

```
$lists = Users::where ( function ( $query ) USE ($username) {
              $query->where('login_username','like','%'.$username.'%')
                     ->orWhere('phoneno', "LIKE", '%'.$username.'%');
         })->whereBetween('dateofjoining',array($fromDate, $toDate))  
         ->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in your query but you have to extend the scope of variables you use inside extended where ( see change in the first line of code you should add use () and all variables used inside to extend their scope to the closure

```
$lists = Users::where ( function ( $query ) use ($username) {
              $query->where('login_username','like','%'.$username.'%')
                    ->or_where("phoneno", "LIKE", '%'.$username.'%');
         })->whereBetween('dateofjoining',array($fromDate, $toDate))  
         ->paginate(5);
```